# Signal messenger app not starting up

Tags: signal

Over the past 2 weeks (after installing Ubuntu 18.04 from scratch) I have had problems on and off with the Signal messenger app. It sometimes doesn't start up at all. Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't seem to help. I think this happened after some Ubuntu updates came through.
Any idea how to get Signal running again?

Comment: The `signal` tag appears to be often misinterpreted on askubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There was something wrong with the snap package install. I unstalled the signal snap package, then downloaded Signal from  their website and installed it without any further problems.

Comment: I recently reinstalled it and was glad to see how much it improved. It is now my favorite way to _copy-paste_ information from my mobile to my desktop.